# hiding submit button before webpage scanning

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a form which contains 3 field.title content tage after that user can submit the form . i want to add one field link where users has to submit the  backlink to my site. after tht i want to scan the link and want to search for the keyword and want to exclude my url from th link users will submit.then only the submit button should appear. otherwise user will submit my link only in link column and it will result ok and submit button will appear any help will be highly appreciated

for ex

title:  title of post

content: body of post

tags:   tags

link :http://XYZ.com/anypage.html (i want to scan this page for my keyword  before showing the submit button.if keyword forund show the submit button or error message

Submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is a workflow.

First, you want to read a page. You should do this with [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). With the response, you should get a valid HTML document back. If you don't, then the URL doesn't exist and show a failure message.

Next, you will want to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML and attempt to find your keyword with the DOM.

Now you know whether or not the keyword exists. Since you want to show a submit button only if the keyword is found, you will want to wrap this entire workflow inside of an AJAX call. You can use any javascript library to do this, but my preference is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This allows you to disable the button until the AJAX call is finished, in which case you can finally do what you wish based on that response.

I originally said you need a workflow, because obviously this is a lot of work. Unfortunately building a complete system like this is out of the scope for volunteers at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can't request the html content from another domain with ajax, that is prevented by cross-domain policies.

You will need to implement this on a server.

So for example in PHP use this:

```
$pagecontent = file_get_contents('http://XYZ.com/anypage.html');
```

And then you will need to use `stripos` or functions like that (or an regular expression) to isolate the information from the pages sourcecode.

We would need a specific sample of code to scan for a more precise answer about the "scanning"

Comment: @badiir how to do by any method